# Snakemake: How to force the creation of all conda environments

Tags: python, conda, snakemake

I am aware that by adding the option `--conda-create-envs-only` you are able to create the conda environments for the workflow. However, would it be possible to force the creation of all conda environments under `workflow/envs/` without knowing the workflow DAG in advance?

The reason is that I am planning to run snakemake on an HPC, and the compute nodes have no internet. As such I have to set up the environment in a build node with internet. The problem is that I can only access my input data in the compute nodes.

Comment: If the HPC cluster has singularity, then `--containerize` might be a workable solution (see [docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#containerization-of-conda-based-workflows)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe make the creation of the conda environments a target itself? Something like, not tested:

```
localrules: all, make_envs

rule all:
    input:
        # Maybe not needed:
        expand('{env}.done', env= ['env1', 'env2'])


rule make_envs:
    conda:
        'workflow/envs/{env}.yaml',
    output:
        touch('{env}.done'),


rule one:
    input:
        'env1.done',
    conda:
        'workflow/envs/env1.yaml',
    output: ...
    shell: ...
```

Rule `one` will find the conda env created because it needs `env1.done` as input

Comment: This is something that I currently have, thanks! I was hoping for maybe some command-line option that I missed or something similar, but I guess it has not been implemented.